# How to solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in React

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, splidejs

I am new to React and using APIs and struggling to resolve this error. I am trying to display a splide of images using React.js and get the following error:

Popular.jsx:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Underneath this error I also get the following error:

The above error occurred in the  component:at Popular (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:120:80)
at div
at Home
at div
at Pages
at div
at App
Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

Please advise how I can resolve this error. I have tried youtube and google but can't seem to solve this error.

My code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Splide, SplideSlide } from '@splidejs/react-splide';
import '@splidejs/splide/dist/css/splide.min.css';

function Popular() {
  const [popular, setPopular] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPopular();
  }, []);
  console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY);
  const getPopular = async () => {
    const api = await fetch(
      `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&number=9`
    );
    const data = await api.json();

    setPopular(data.recipes);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper>
        <h3>Popular Picks</h3>
        <Splide
          options={{
            perPage: 4,
            arrows: false,
            pagination: false,
            drag: 'free',
            gap: '5rem'
          }}
        >
          {popular.map((recipe) => {
            return (
              <SplideSlide>
                <Card>
                  <p>{recipe.title}</p>
                  <img src={recipe.image} alt={recipe.title} />
                </Card>
              </SplideSlide>
            );
          })}
        </Splide>
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
}

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  margin: 4rem 0rem;
`;

const Card = styled.div`
min-height: 25rem;
border-radius: 2rem;
overFlow: hidden;
position: relative;

img{
border-radius: 2rem;
position: absoute;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
}

p{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 40%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}

`;

export default Popular;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your state correctly with an empty array, so `.map` shouldn't throw an error.

I suspect something is wrong with your API key/call/response. Try logging the response after this line: `const data = await api.json();`.

For example, if I call the API without a key I get the following response:

```
  { 
    status: "failure", 
    code: 401, message: 
    "You are not authorized. Please read https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Authentication" 
  }
```

If you have an error and call `setPopular(data.recipes);`, you're basically saying `setPopular(undefined)`. And `undefined.map(...)` will throw an error.

A catch-all solution is to check if `popular` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

In your render method change `{popular.map((recipe) => {` to
`{popular && popular.map((recipe) => {`

Or, if you want to make sure you get no errors, you can check if `popular` is an array:
`{Array.isArray(popular) && popular.map((recipe) => {`

You can use something similar to this to render a different component when there is no data:

```
  if (popular) {
    <SplideSlide>...</SplideSlide>
  } else {
    <NoSlidesAvailableComponent />
  }
```

Comment: the API key is as follows: REACT_APP_API_KEY=12299e135dba4708a8edb0a788aae23f

Comment: If I change {popular.map((recipe) => { to {popular && popular.map((recipe) => {

then the uncaught type error goes away but  I get the following error:

Popular.jsx:14          GET https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apiKey=71e9601785ed4c919af2fa6f4e0bfe96&number=9 401

Comment: Please remove your comment with your API key. Anyone will be able to use that key now. A 401 means you are unauthorized, so your API key is wrong. Please check the api keys in your account on the spoonacular website!

Comment: Hi thanks but its no problem. Its a free key because I am just practicing for now to work with APIs. I did check my key on the website and it is exactly the same.

Comment: Hmm any chance you have put a space at the end of your key? I tried to use your key and noticed there is an additional space at the end when I copied it from your comment. If I remove that space, I get a response, but now it says: 'Your daily points limit of 150 has been reached.' Hope this helps